# What does the 2 temperatures mean in the Weather app?

Tags: weather.app

In the Weather app, there are 2 temperatures for each day. What does these mean?

Answer (score 6):

That's the day's forcasted high and low temperature

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yep, predicted high and low. This is also true of the pairs of numbers at the end of each row. They are also temperatures in your settings' selected temperature scale.

Answer (score -3):

There is 2 temperature which showing highest and lowest.

Lowest mostly midnight
Highest mostly middle of Day like 1 AM to 2 PM

Thanks

Comment: That's not necessarily true, as the coolest temperature is usually just before dawn. Besides that, what additional information does your answer provide, that hasn't been given already in the other two questions..?